# how do I match columns in two worksheets in excel

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I need to perform a "full-outer-join" scenerio between tabs in an excel workbook.

I have a column of items in worksheet1, and a column of items in worksheet2

example:

```
Worksheet1:
item1
item2
item3

worksheet2:
item1
item2
item4
```

I am trying to create a pivottable to perform a comparison on items that match, missing in worksheet1, and missing in worksheet2.

Example:

```
Match:
wksht1  wksht2
item1   item1
item2   item2
item3   <blank>
<blank> item4

Not Match by Wksheet1
wksht1  wksht2
item3   <blank>

Not Match by Wksheet2
wksht1   wksht2
<blank>  item4
```

I believe a pivot table is good here,
but it's asking me to match keys...
I need a value comparison.

How can I accomplish this?

UPDATE #1, I cannot use coloring or shading...It must show the value with the original color and shading.  Thanks.

Thanks

Comment: Why did you tag with Powerpivot? And where does color come in before your "update"? Don't try and prescribe a method (pivot table), just state the input and the desired output. If color is a factor, include that in your problem description. Edit your question to make these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just (1) copy all the items from both pages into a common list, (2) Data > Remove Duplicates (3) Use two columns of countif formulas to see if they are in the original lists and (4) Sort the output by these values?

Regarding color, what should it be if the two sources are not consistent (e.g. item1 is red in the first and blue in the second file)?